# Heat from a cold reservoir to a hotter system, which is converting it to work?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Recently I had encountered this question, "Derive an expression for the maximum work done by $1$ mole of a monoatomic ideal gas, initially contained in a cylinder of volume $V_0$ at a temperature $T_0$ as it expands to a volume $V_f = 2V_0$. Assume that the system is connected to a thermal reservoir at a temperature of $T_{\rm res} = \frac{3T_0}{4}$."

My initial approach did lead to the answer given in the solution, and this is how it went: Assuming the system + reservoir to be the universe, we have by the second law,

$$ 
\Delta S_{\rm univ} \geq 0 \\
\Delta S_{\rm sys} - \frac{Q_{\rm sys}}{T_{\rm res}} \geq 0 \\
Q_{\rm sys} \leq T_{\rm res}\Delta S_{\rm sys}
$$

From the first law, we have (for work done by the system, we have a negative sign in front of the work):
$$
-W_{\rm sys} \leq -\Delta U_{\rm sys} + T_{\rm res}\Delta S_{\rm sys}
$$

Now since $U$ and $S$ are state functions in the system, given the initial and final states, we are able to calculate the change. For maximum work, equality must hold. Solving for these, we get the maximum work done as:

$$ \text{Work done by the system} = \frac{3}{4}T_0[R \ln 2 + C_v \ln\frac{3}{4}] + \frac{1}{4}C_vT_0$$
But after thinking sbout this for a bit, I realised there is net heat flow from the cold reservoir to the hot system (which in it's final state is in thermodynamic equilibrium). My initial doubt was that does this lead to a violation of the second law? But more thinking led me to doubt the very conditions equality holds. Our initial state is not in thermodynamic equilibrium with the reservoir, but the path of maximum work is a reversible one (as implied by the entropy change being equal to zero in the total isolated universe). Reversible path implied that at every point the system is in equilibrium with it's surroundings. Is there some fallacy in my understanding?Under these conditions, what should be the maximum work done be?

PS: One more point against the argument of reversible work is that $dS = dQ(\frac{1}{T_{\rm sys}} - \frac{1}{T_{\rm res}}) \neq 0$ in this case, hence some irreversibility has to exist.

Comment: The question is, can you conceive of a reversible process that can bring these changes about?

Comment: Doesn't the very notion of reversibility require thermodynamic equilibrium? If the system is not at equilibrium in the very beginning, how can it have a reversible process?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, so....?  I think what they meant by the last sentence is "Assume that all the heat exchange with the surroundings must take place using an ideal thermal reservoir at $3T_0/4$."

Comment: Suppose the process consists of 2 steps, and the first step is an adiabatic reversible expansion.

Comment: Actually, the given answer is incorrect for the case of a diatomic ideal gas, or any ideal gas with $\gamma\geq\ about\ 1.4$

Comment: Again, the first step being adiabatic reversible is what I thought later. But for complete process to be reversible, that's the only option. That gives a different solution.

Comment: Step 1:  Expand the gas adiabatically and reversibly to whatever volume V* ($<2V_0$) is necessary to lower its temperature from $T_0$ to $\frac{3T_0}{4}$.  Step 2:  Expand the gas isothermally (at temperature $\frac{3T_0}{4}$) and reversibly from V* to $2V_0$ (receiving heat from the reservoir).